# Angular2 - Import multiple modules

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, angular

I have done the Tutorial-Guide on [www.angular.io](http://www.angular.io) and now I'm trying to implement my own Angular2-Component.

My Typescript looks like this:

```
import {bootstrap, Component, FORM_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/angular2'
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http'
@Component({
    selector: 'Abrechnung',
    template: `
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <li *ng-for="#posten of postenliste">
            {{posten.text}}
        </li>
    `,
    viewProviders: [HTTP_PROVIDERS],
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES],
})
```

While the first import loads correctly, the browser looks for the http-module in the wrong folder. I also can't see where the first module is coming from. In my networktrace there is no 'angular2/angular2' call. Are these modules included inside the angular2 - library?

I am using Visual Studio for development. I think everything is set up the same as in the tutorial.

Where can I find additional information about the "import ... from" stuff in Typescript? I am not sure which syntax-versions I am using here :-/

Thx!

Comment: Did you add the http module? i.e `http.dev.js`, `http.min.js`, `http.js`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I had to reference the http.dev.js. I was missing that one.

Thought the system.js is doing the magic here.

Thx to Eric!

Answer (score 0):

'angular2/angular2' is a prepacked module bundle on the system.js module loader. It is not a path.
But of course you can load own modules given a path like './your_directory/your_filename'

Comment: "angular2/angular2" is not longer available on angular2-beta0.
You should import each module individually. (ex: angular2/core, angular2/common, angular2/http, and so on)